# Android studio throwing this exception while running flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1288)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:732)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
  at java.Kbase/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:247)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:191)
```

Comment: Please include what are you trying to do, and share [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code

Answer (score 1):

delete .gradle file from the root directory